# jboss failed to define class javax.jms.JMSException

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am new to JBoss. I had an Ear file worked OK on WAS. But when I tried it on the JBoss EAP 7.1, it gave me the below error.

```
14:15:18,640 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-6) Failed to define class javax.jms.JMSException in Module "deployment.xxx.ear.yyy.war:mai
n" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Failed to link javax/jms/JMSException (Module "xxx.ear.yyy.war:main" from Service
 Module Loader): Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/jms/JMSException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:605)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFManagedBeanProcessor.deploy(JSFManagedBeanProcessor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

14:15:18,640 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."xxx.ear"."yyy.war
".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."xxx.ear"."yyy.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process
 phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "yyy.war" of deployment "xxx.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Failed to link javax/jms/JMSException (Module "deployment.xxx.ear.yyy.war:main" from Service Module Loader): Abs
ent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/jms/JMSException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:605)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFManagedBeanProcessor.deploy(JSFManagedBeanProcessor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
```

From the research, it seems the issue of the dependency, which has interface only.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
   <version>6.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

So I changed to

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0-5</version>
  </dependency>
```

But no luck. I am also looking for a jar like j2ee.jar. I could find one jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec-1.0.0.Final-redhat-1.jar under JBoss runtime. But it doesn't contain anything on javax.jms.*.

Also I looked at class loading. Patched ear file with jboss-deployment-structure.xml with content to eliminating double class loading.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure> 
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>    
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you really using the 2 day old JBoss EAP 7.1 Alpha release?

Comment: Changed to EAP 7.0. The same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `javax.javaee-api.6.0` maven dependency has a single [well documented](http://adambien.blog/roller/abien/entry/trouble_with_crippled_java_ee) problem - the byte code for any implementation classes that it needs has been stripped, resulting in the `java.lang.ClassFormatError`.

The reason you are seeing this is because even though your `dependency` says `<scope>provided</scope>`, a copy of this jar has leaked into your application deployment somewhere. You need to get rid of it.

Once you have done this you can upgrade the dependency to `<version>7.0</version>` which does not have this problem (which is normally only an issue for unit tests that depend upon it).

Comment: Change to <dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
   <version>7.0</version>
</dependency> fixed it.